# For the condition: f is continuous on [0,1], takes on no rational values. Can f(x) = 1?

Tags: calculus

If I was to draw a graph for the given condition:

- f is continuous on [0,1], takes on no rational values

and I draw f(x) = 1, will that be correct?

- When it says f takes on no rational values, it means f(x) $\ne$ any rational number right?

Comment: Is $f$ the same as $F$?  Capitalization is usually considered significant in math.  If they're the same, then $f(x)$ can never have the (rational) value $1$.

Comment: Not sure this is clear. Is $F(x)$ different from $f(x)$? if so, what is the connection between them?  $1$ is rational, so the function $f(x)=1$ doesn't satisfy your condition.

Comment: sorry fixed the confusion, they are the same

Comment: It's a yes or no question. You have to ask yourself whether 1 is rational and the answer to that will be the answer. Also, as others have commented capital and lowercase letters are not interchangeable. Even if it's at the beginning of a sentence, it remains lowercase if its name is lowercase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $f$ must be constant (and of irrational value): Suppose that it took on at least two values, with $f_1 = f(x_1)$ not equal to $f_2 = f(x_2)$ (where $x_1 < x_2$ without loss of generality).  By continuity and the intermediate value theorem, $f(x)$ over $[x_1, x_2]$ must take on all values between $f_1$ and $f_2$.  In particular, it must take on any rational value between $f_1$ and $f_2$, and by the denseness of the reals, there must be at least one (in fact, an infinite number) of such values.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = 1$ does not work because $1$ is rational.

Pick your favorite irrational number and take $f$ constant equal to that number.

eg   $f(x) = \pi$

Comment: $f(x)$ does not have to be between $0$ and $1$; The domain is $[0,1]$, not the range.

Comment: @EthanZed thanks! corrected :)